# 2006 Kia sedona has a burnt electrical smell

Tags: smell, kia

My 2006 Kia Sedona has a burnt electrical smell but the van is running fine right now although it did seem to be acting like it was loosing power but then was fine we are at a loss any ideas

Comment: A little more information would be helpful.  For instance, when did you smell the smell? how did you know it was electrical? did everyone in the car smell the same thing? or was it localized?

Answer (score 1):

Since your car has a burnt electrical smell and acts like losing its power, you can check its wiring system and the fuse for possible short circuits. It will be much better if a professional mechanic assists you in repairing your car. After all, the wiring systems of cars can be very intricate, and a single mistake can cause a myriad of problems right away.